# gel substance to keep food moist?

Tags: sushi, fresh

I've seen this in mostly chain supermarket and Costco.

When they make sushi, they would brush this clear gel like substance on the sushi maki roll either to keep it moist or fresh for long period of time. Anyone know what that stuff is call?

Comment: just fyi, this doesn't sound appetizing lol

Comment: It could just be simple syrup. I know that's brushed on pastries sometimes to keep them moist. Sushi rice is already sweetened, so the extra sugar might not be too noticeable.

Comment: @rfusca, that is why I don't buy sushi from those places, no matter if it's on sale or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is likely to be guar or xanthan gum

http://www.uwec.edu/Dining/locations/upload/SushiDO_Ingredients.pdf

(Look at one of the items like a Philadelphia roll).

Not very appetising but does keep in 'kind of' fresh

Comment: Looks like they are found in everyday items, canned food, salad dressing, even gluten free bread.